# would happen or would have happened

Tags: word-usage, grammar

What is correct?

- > I wanted to see, what would happen.
- > I wanted to see, what would have happened.
- > I want to see, what would happen
- > I want to see, what will happen.

Answer (score 2):

They are all correct in context although you don't need the comma.

> I wanted to see what would happen **when the fuse was lit**.

Here you are describing an action in the past that is not complete.

> I wanted to see what would have happened **if the fuse had been lit**.

Here you are describing an action in the past based on a condition **if the fuse had been lit**.

> I want to see what would happen **if the fuse is lit**.

Here you are describing an action in the present based on a condition **if the fuse is lit**.

> I want to see what will happen **when the fuse is lit**.

Here you are describing an action in the present that is incomplete.

There are other options too but the differences between your sentences (as I have completed them) are that some are set in the past and others in the present. And that some are conditional and others not.